# How to programmatically create a add to cart form with quantity input?

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I want to programmatically create an add to cart form with quantity input and default as 1. I tried to use the code:

```
$form_id= commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_id(array($product_id));  
$product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
$line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1);  
$line_item->data['context']['product_ids'] = array($product_id);
$form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $line_item);
```

But it just get a hidden field quantity with value 1 and I cannot change the quantity value. How can I get a quantity input instead of the static value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. I would have never thought to do this. A quick search in the commerce module produced this example:

```
<?php
// line 2649 of commerce_cart.module

// Extract the drupal_get_form() arguments array from the element.
$arguments = $element[$key]['#arguments'];

// Add the display path and referencing entity data to the line item.
if (!empty($entity_uri['path'])) {
  $arguments['line_item']->data['context']['display_path'] = $entity_uri['path'];
}

$arguments['line_item']->data['context']['entity'] = array(
  'entity_type' => $context['entity_type'],
  'entity_id' => $entity_id,
  'product_reference_field_name' => $field_name,
);

// Update the product_ids variable to point to the entity data if we're
// referencing multiple products.
if (count($arguments['line_item']->data['context']['product_ids']) > 1) {
  $arguments['line_item']->data['context']['product_ids'] = 'entity';
}

// Replace the array containing the arguments with the return value of
// drupal_get_form(). It will be rendered when the rest of the object is
// rendered for display.
$output[$field_name][$key] = drupal_get_form($arguments['form_id'], $arguments['line_item'], $arguments['show_quantity'], $cart_context);
?>
```

Which means you could do this:

```
<?php
$product_id = 1;
$form_id= commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_id(array($product_id));  
$product = commerce_product_load($product_id);
$line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1);  
$line_item->data['context']['product_ids'] = array($product_id);
$form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $line_item, true);
dpm($form);
?>
```

And you will see how it affects the quantity (makes it become a proper field). You're also missing the $cart_context that the core module uses to determine what to do with displaying/hiding fields.